# Set proxy for terminal and I cannot redirect properly using axios

Tags: node.js, linux, http, request, axios

After set proxy i cannot redirect properly.

This is part of the error log, and i can clearly find the the _currentUrl is wrong, it should be `https://service-staging.myweb.io/datahub/convertor/api/sp/packages` but now it comes with prxoy i set at terminal at the head of the url.I am using node.js and axios to send the request.
Thank you for any helping.

```
[] [2020-09-20T22:18:59.996+0800] [] [ERROR] [] Error: timeout of 60000ms exceeded
    at createError (/Users/jdh/Desktop/dashboard/server/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at Timeout.handleRequestTimeout [as _onTimeout] (/Users/jdh/Desktop/dashboard/server/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:216:16)
request{
  _currentUrl: 'https://127.0.0.1:6152/https://service-staging.myweb.io/datahub/convertor/api/sp/packages'
}
```

This is how I set proxy at terminal

```
export https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:6152;
export http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:6152;
export all_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:6153
```